# It keeps saying "identifier 'COUNTRY_NAME' must be declared" when it already is?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I used this coded in PL/SQL but I keep getting errors:

> ORA-06550: line 10, column 4:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'COUNTRY_NAME' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

And I can't find out what's wrong with it, thank you in advance! :)

This is my code

```
 DECLARE 
 v_country_name countries.country_name%TYPE :=  'United States of America'; 
 v_lowest_elevation countries.lowest_elevation%TYPE; 
 v_highest_elevation countries.highest_elevation%TYPE; 
 BEGIN 
 SELECT lowest_elevation, highest_elevation 
 INTO v_lowest_elevation, v_highest_elevation
 FROM countries; 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The lowest elevation in 
 '||country_name||' is '||v_lowest_elevation 
 ||' and the highest elevation is '|| 
 v_highest_elevation||'.'); 
 END;
```

Comment: It "keeps saying"? How many times did you try? Did you change anything between the tries? If not, why did you even try more than once?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.

In your first line, you wrote `v_country_name` (with the `v_`) and in your 10th line you wrote `country_name` without the `v_`

Comment: Once you correct for above you will have trouble with the select. That is unless your table has exactly 1 row. If the table has no rows it will throw a "no_data_found" exception. Without a where clause it will attempt to retrieve every row in the table, but the INTO permits only 1 row, any more it throws a "too_many_rows" exception. I suggest you look into the documentation for "Select into", Exception Handling, and perhaps basic cursor processing.  If you still have issues afterward please ask another question.